How to get the correct Work Item ID in Azure Devops - Power Automate
I'm trying to write a simple flow in Power Automate that when Work Item is created. Get work Item Details of Parent Work Item (User Story) and then update Work Item of Child Tasks with the Sizing value from Parent Work Item.
In 'Update Work Item" I've chosen "ID of work item" but it populates the ID of the Parent Item instead of the Child Task. I've clearly indicated the Work Item Type to be Task though.
When I manually put a Child Task ID in there, the flow works.
What should I choose for Work Item ID if it's not ID in order to grab the Child Task ID?
enter image description here


What should I choose for Work Item ID if it's not ID in order to grab the Child Task ID?

When you use Power Automate, you can add the action: Get work item children to get the correct ID of the Child task.
For example:

In Get work item children action, you can use the Parent Work item Id from the action: Get work item details.
For example:

Then you can use the child task id in the update work item action.
For example:

